# How to get rid of this number popup in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I get this number notification every time I type anything in VS code. How can I get rid of this?[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEr9E.png)

Comment: That is one of your extensions - maybe `power-<something>`.

Comment: @Mark thank you! Yes it was due to power-mode extension that I used because I liked the sparkling effect while typing.